# Xcode thrown into an endless loop by command line project

Tags: objective-c, xcode, compiler-construction, command-line

I'm trying to build a command-line > foundation application under XCode4.
While running the app under LLVM 2.0 i get the following 3 errors:

```
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Headers/CGPDFContext.h:60:23: error: expected function body after function declarator [3]
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Frameworks/HIServices.framework/Headers/AXUIElement.h:65:74: error: unknown type name 'CGCharCode' [3]
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Frameworks/HIServices.framework/Headers/AXUIElement.h:65:94: error: unknown type name 'CGKeyCode' [3]
```

When setting the compiler to GCC 4.2 or LLVM GCC 4.2 it throws XCode into a loop and i have to force it to shut down.

The code in the main.h looks as follows.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    NSMutableArray *items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [items addObject:@"One"];
    [items addObject:@"Two"];
    [items addObject:@"Three"];
    [items insertObject:@"Zero" atIndex:0];

    for(int i = 0; i < [items count]; i++)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", [items objectAtIndex:i]);
    }

    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

Does anyone know a solution?

Comment: Can't find the problem, no infinite loop here with me. Is this part of a bigger app? Or just a templated project?

Comment: Upgrade to the latest version of Xcode 4. I had unending compilations with earlier releases on projects with cyclic dependencies, and wouldn't be surprised to see other wonky problems solved by upgrading.

Comment: Which frameworks are you including in your project, and what's the content of your .pch file? It looks like the compiler may be trying to load something from the Core Graphics framework, which doesn't make sense for a command-line application.

Comment: @Nick Weaver, it's a templated project, i only added the items stuff

Comment: @Jeremy W. Sherman, i DID install it over XCode3, i will try a reinstall of xcode4

Comment: @Zophiel, I am using Build 4A278b which are you using? And I have XCode3 and 4 running on my system.

Comment: @Scott Forbes, i'm only including the Foundation framework. It's what i selected during the creation of the project. the .pch is only including foundation. 

#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#endif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oke so.. after lots of forums to be dug through I ended up uninstalling any XCode i had and cleaning out the developer directory.
Redownloading XCode 3 and XCode 4.
Installing both their own respective directories and what do you know.

It works..!

Probably some mess left from upgrading XCode 3 was making my XCode go loopy.